# How to implement IApiVersionDescriptionProvider to Program.cs in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6.

I'm doing make Versioning for my Web API Core. And I got stucked when implementing the IApiVersionDescriptionProvider into Program.cs.

Beacuse of when creating a new project ASP.NET Core Web API, there only the program.cs file. (The old .NET Core have Startup.cs and Program.cs)

Please help me, Thanks all
Here is my code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Reflection;
using VfcSolution.Application.User;
using VfcSolution.WebApi;
using VfcSolution.WebApi.VfcSolutionMapper;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, OracleUserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(VfcSolutionMappings));

builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options => options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV");

builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{   
    ==> I'M STUCKED IN HERE, I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO IMPLEMENT IApiVersionDescriptionProvider
    foreach (var desc in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {

    }
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to add the following line after `builder.Build()`;

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;

 var app = builder.Build();
 var provider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
```

Comment: without adding this you will face "No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiVersionDescriptionProvider' has been registered." error.

'
    builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
    {
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    });
'


reference https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/0e0372c3c1d895c3ce195ba983b1e03d

Comment: For me I had extracted the Configure() method into different file and my method was accepting  `IApplicationBuilder` that was the problem once I changed the type to `WebApplication` it worked fine